# Creating a DefauitComboBoxModel class

Tags: java, class, types

I need to create a bunch of JComboBoxes all alike. I am trying to use DefaultComboBoxModel to generate the model. However, I also need to create several different models based on the data to be included in the list. Therefore I created a class which I want to use to generate the model.

```
public class ModelComboBox<T> {

    public ModelComboBox(ArrayList<String> list_) {
        DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model=new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>();
        for (String entry : list_) {
            model.addElement(entry);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to use the model I get a ModelComboBox.ModelComboBox cannot be resolved to a type error.

```
meatNames=new JComboBox<String>(new ModelComboBox.ModelComboBox<String>(meats));
```

Can someone help me with the syntax of telling it what the type is for ModelComboBox.ModelComboBox? I tried various placements of (DefaultComboBoxModel) in the argument but nothing I tried works. TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems here.

First, ModelComboBox is a top-level class. The syntax for calling its constructor, as for any other top-level class, is `new ModelComboBox<String>()`, not `new ModelComboBox.ModelComboBox<String>()`.

Second, this class is a generic class, but it doesn't use its generic type (T) anywhere. So it has absolutely no reason to be generic.

Third, its constructor creates a DefaultComboBoxModel, and assigns it to a local variable. When the constructor completes, the DefaultComboBoxModel thus goes out of scope, becomes eligible to GC, and is thus not usable anywhere.

Finally, you pass an instance of ModelComboBox to the constructor of JComboBox. But JComboBox expects an instance of ComboBoxModel, not an instance of ModelComboBox. So that can't compile.

You're completely overthinking this, IMO. All you need is some helper method allowing to take a `List<String>` and to create a DefaultComboBoxModel from that list:

```
public DefaultComboBoxModel<String> createComboBoxModel(List<String> list) {
    return new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(new Vector<>(list));
}
```

Comment: Well that certainly is a lot easier. However, when I create your helper method, I get this error: DefaultComboBoxModel is a raw type. References to generic type DefaultComboBoxModel<E> should be parameterized

Comment: Correction, that is a warning not an error. I can ignore it but is there a way to get rid of it? Thanks for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

JB Nizet's explanation is very good, but I'd modify it just a bit.

```
public ModelComboBox(ArrayList<String> list) {
    setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<String>(list.toArray());
}
```

There is no need to create a `Vector`.  The `ArrayList` implements the `List` interface, which assures a `.toArray()` method.

All Swing Components that support a model have a `setModel(...)` function, which takes the type of model the `Component` supports.

Comment: That won't compile. toArray() returns an Object[], but the constructor expects a String[]. You would need to use `list.toArray(new String[list.size()])`.

Comment: @JBNizet I type from memory many times, so no, I didn't run it through a complier.  I also believe you could use list.toArray<String>().  But

Comment: That wouldn't be valid Java, and toArray() is not a generic method anway.

Comment: You're right toArray() isn't generic, leaving your example as the best one.